# What JS Runtime am I using on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm on Rails 5.1 and I've started getting this error message after installing Bootstrap gem:

> JScript runtime does’t support ES6. Please update or replace your current ExecJS runtime.

Raising this error from this line:

"<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>"

How can I check the version of my JSCRIPT Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Add following gems to you Gemfile and do `bundle install`

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

Alternatively, You can install `sudo apt-get install nodejs`(on Ubuntu) to fix this for all the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post with some info on finding out [which version of JScript you're running](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74e25a55-64da-495f-99e9-5f9a29ab8e4e/determine-version-of-jscript?forum=jscript)

I'm not sure that is helpful though, it's not clear if JScript supports ES6 at all.

execjs supports multiple runtimes: https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

You should be able to add `gem 'mini_racer'` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` to fix the error message.